# Benevolent/Malevolent Deities

Tags: pantheon

For a project I'm working on, I need to divide deities of various pantheons into "benevolent" (deities who work for/strive for the betterment of humanity and the world) and "malevolent" (deities who work for/strive for the death and destruction of humanity and the world) camps. I'm at a loss and every attempt at researching this only gave me Tv Tropes or personal feelings over certain deities, neither of which were useful to me. Anyone out there got ideas? Or some direction to point me in?

Comment: I don't think the gods in most pantheons are so easily divided into benevolent and malevolent. Like humans, it's often just how the mood strikes them. If you haven't gone in the direction of wikipedia yet, that would be my suggestion for [an overview of pantheons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_pantheons) and the gods therein. And from there, if necessary, you could branch out to more primary/scholarly sources.

Comment: Not to mention that they are often wildly inconsistent.

Comment: Yes, the idea of a strict binary, good gods versus evil gods, is not found in most cultures. You haven't mentioned which pantheons you're trying to divide in this way, but I would hazard a guess that the reason you can't find good sources on this topic is that there aren't any. Even the Christian G-d has wanted to destroy humanity a few times.